# While storing feature in ArcGIS 10 web application getting Class is not licensed for use

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcmap, arcgis-server, 32bit, db2

I have tried googling this issue

> Class is not licensed for use

but I could not found Any Solution .

I am using ArcGIS Server 10.0 of 32 bit and IBM DB2 32 bit,there is no problem while startEdting operation but  while storing feature(pFeature.store()) it is giving me this issue.

Has anyone already faced this issue?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.  If you have ArcFM enabled for your geodatabase then this sounds a lot like https://geonet.esri.com/thread/43161  What version of DB2 are you using?

Comment: ArcGIS 10.0 has been Retired for over 13 months. All support for 32-bit databases ended with it. It will be difficult  to find anyone who has a matching configuration to test/validate your code.